# Problema con API de Google Maps Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hoy les vengo a pedir una ayuda ya que tengo un problema con un autocompletador de registro que me esta dando vueltas y no puedo solucionar es sobre una api de google maps javascript.

Lo que quiero es que en el autocompletador de cuidad funcione la API como en esta imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero a mi me sale el error este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el script que estoy usando:

```
<script type="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places&key=AIzaSyANHGO0Y2f8bQ-Owt4Yjgn9uf5U29sJHY8"></script>
```

enlace: www.tuscitas.com

Comment: Hola, es más fácil si editas tu pregunta y agregas el código relevante.

Comment: Si te fijas en la consola de chrome, te aparece el error: básicamente no has ingresado las credenciales de autenticación de la API.

Comment: ya actualice el script con la API, No sale el error pero aun sigue sin funcionar no salen las ciudades o paises.

Comment: @Shaz ya actualice el script con la API, peor no me sale las ubicaciones

Comment: @AeikoSanchez, si en la consola no sale error, mira la pestaña "Network" de la herramienta; allí podrás ver las peticiones que se están haciendo; es posible que allí las peticiones terminen súbitamente. Debes mantener la consola (F12) abierta mientras haces estas pruebas.

Comment: Por favor añade el código necesario para reproducir el problema en la misma pregunta. Los enlaces pueden romperse y dejar de funcionar (y tu pregunta dejará de tener sentido) o puedes solucionar el problema, por lo que dejará de producirse en el enlace (y tu pregunta dejará de tener sentido).

Answer (score 1):

Aeiko, revisa bien el codigo subido a tu Host.

Al inspeccionar el código fuente, veo que estas incluyendo la lib así:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMapGoogle" async defer></script>
```

**Probar incluirla así**, reemplazando '{DOMAIN_API_KEY}' por tu key:

```
<script type="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&callback=initMapGoogle&key={DOMAIN_API_KEY}"></script>
```

Si sabes usar, por ejemplo, DevTools de Google Chrome, en "Consola" se puede ver el siguiente error:

- Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error

Claramente te falta poner tu **API Key**